# Website falsely blocked because of spam. Does anyone know how we should proceed?

Tags: facebook, spam

I'm responsible for ICT at FOS Open Scouting, a belgian scouting organisation.

Our website was hacked a few years back and blocked by Facebook as a result. After we regained control over the site Facebook continued to block our domain and this is causing us a number of problems.

We have tried many times in the past year to contact Facebook using their 'I am blocked from adding content' form (https://www.facebook.com/help/contact.php?show_form=block_appeal) to no avail. We get the response "Thanks for contacting Facebook. You should receive an email response shortly.". The email has the following response: "Thanks for taking the time to submit this report. While we don't currently provide individual support for this issue, this information will help us identify bugs on our site."

The blocked URLs are: http://www.fos.be and http://www.fosopenscouting.be

Does anyone know how we should/could proceed?

EDIT: The problem has been resolved. For anyone who finds itself in the situation above: Send a letter to Facebook HQ (1601 Willow Road, Menlo Park, CA 94025 if you reside in the U.S. or Canada, or at Facebook Ireland Ltd., Hanover Reach, 5-7 Hanover Quay, Dublin 2 Ireland if you live outside the U.S. or Canada).

Comment: This is a 3rd party developer site.  We developers have no relation with Facebook other than we use their public APIs. Maybe you should contact Facebook by telephone.

Comment: Would you mind edit the question to contain FB's automatic response when using their online form? This helps people finding this page. Mainly "Thanks for taking the time to submit this report. While we don't currently provide individual support for this issue, this information will help us identify bugs on our site."

Comment: No problem, just added the minimal response of Facebook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem has been resolved. For anyone who finds itself in the situation above: Send a letter to

```
Facebook HQ 
1601 Willow Road
Menlo Park, CA 94025
```

Or if you live outside the U.S. or Canada

```
Facebook Ireland Ltd.
Hanover Reach
5-7 Hanover Quay
Dublin 2 Ireland
```

---

An additional success story from Patti Ryan:

Facebook blocked use of our URL for years, yes years. For some reason no one could include our website URL (a-fib.com) in any post, or even on our own FB page. They'd get an error message saying our site had been flagged as spammy. This had been going on for years! FB has zero customer service.

Here's what worked. After trying everything else over the course of three years, we finally resorted to writing a pleading letter on our letterhead, asking why would anyone block a non-profit trying to help heart patients? We sent it 'registered mail' to FB headquarters. (Advice I found among other ideas online from those with a similar problem.)  It worked.

Comment: Thomas When you wrote to the FB HQ who or what department was the letter addressed to? What information did you include in the letter? Thank you

Comment: I send a registered letter to the address above, without a person or department. In the letter I mentioned the blocked domains and I explained what my organisation does in order to proof that blocking our domains is a mistake.

Comment: I never got an actual response by the way, but after a couple of weeks our domains weren't blocked anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Getting a response out of facebook seems to be very difficult indeed. I would post your question in the [facebook developers](https://developers.facebook.com/) area perhaps that group may have some better ideas on how to get through.

Otherwise have you considered changing your primary domain?

At the moment both your URLs end up at fos.be. You could purchase a new domain and point your two old URLs to it - hopefully this would get you around the issue without dropping your traffic or ranking so long as you use a 301 redirect.

Comment: This could work, we wanted to do this with our second domain but then we noticed that Facebook had already blocked that one.

Comment: The Facebook developers area takes you to facebook.stackexchange.com, which is where this question was originally posted.

Comment: @paulmorriss the link is to https://developers.facebook.com/ so I don't see how that is possible and the question came from stackoverflow.

Comment: @ThomasCrepain it's possible that they might block a third domain as well but in this situation I would think it's worth a shot so long as both the old sites resolve to the new domain. Its a very sticky situation.

Comment: developers.facebook.com -> https://developers.facebook.com/support/ -> Technical Q&A facebook.stackoverflow.com (which is a pseudo-site displaying everything on stackoverflow.com with a facebook tag)

Comment: Someone seems to have divided by zero.

Comment: @ThomasCrepain ok, I had no idea, but there are other options on that page including the facebook developers group.