# Facebook thinks my site may be unsafe!

Tags: url, facebook, spam

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Website falsely blocked because of spam. Does anyone know how we should proceed?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24997/website-falsely-blocked-because-of-spam-does-anyone-know-how-we-should-proceed)

Whenever anybody clicks on a link that I've posted on any Facebook Page (including my page http://www.facebook.com/GalaxyS4.info) to my website (http://www.galaxy-s4.info/) they get directed to an warning message which reads:

> Facebook thinks this site may be unsafe. If you're not familiar with
>   it, please provide feedback by marking it as spam (you'll be brought
>   back to Facebook)

Any idea why this is happening? Μy site is safe and not a spam site! I've checked with Google Webmaster tools - no issues or malware. I tried to contact facebook to resolve this issue but no lack until now.

**Can anyone suggest what to do?**

Answer (score 0):

You are using Samsung trade mark Galaxy S4 in your url, this might have made Facebook thinks that your links is directing towards some spam site.

I suggest to remove the Galaxy word from the Facebook page URL